# How do you prevent user resubmitting the same search criteria again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript to prevent the user from resubmitting the same search criteria without changing the text (SearchString) or the combo box (SearchType).  The EnableSubmit works but has a problem that when the user adds and then removes a space, EnableSubmit falls over.

I try to keep the value of the last criteria in LastChange variable.  Then when they submit it again, the alert box pops up.  After the alert is closed, the code then looks like it is submitting and then they can then reclick submit with the same previous criteria.  The question is, how can I after the alert box close then keep LastChange with the same value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var LastChange;

    $("#SearchString").change(function () { EnableSubmit();});
    $("#SearchString").keyup(function () { EnableSubmit(); });
    $("#SearchType").change(function () { EnableSubmit(); })

    function EnableSubmit () { $("#SubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled"); $("#SubmitButton").attr("value", "Search"); }

    $(function () {

    $("#StarForm").submit(function (e) { 

        $("#SubmitButton").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#SubmitButton").attr("value", "Submit disabled until you change search criteria.");

        if (LastChange == ($("#SearchString").val())) {
            alert('Please change the search criteria before resubmitting.');
            LastChange = ($("#SearchString").val());

        }
        else {

            LastChange = ($("#SearchString").val());



            var FormData = '{ "SearchString": "' + $('#SearchString').val() + '",' +
                '"SearchType" : "' + $('#SearchType').val() + '"' +
                '}';
            e.preventDefault();

        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: If you have only problem with the spaces,  you can easily remove them with [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method.

Comment: If they add a space and then remove it then pop will appear and then will forget the last change.

Comment: After `alert` not make a sense to overwrite `LastChange` because you are in a "non changed" path, in the else block: you should save `LastChange` trimmed. Another thing: create variable top of the function: `var searchString = $("#SearchString").val().trim();` and use `searchString` variable later. Using the same jquery selector over and over again is a  bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps put the enable/disable logic in your change handler and only set the last search criteria in your submit handler.

Maybe something like this?

```
$(function () {
    var lastSearchText;
    var lastSearchType;

    $("#SearchString").change(function () { onSearchChanged();});
    $("#SearchString").keyup(function () { onSearchChanged(); });
    $("#SearchType").change(function () { onSearchChanged(); })

    function onSearchChanged () { 

        var searchText = $("#SearchString").val().trim();
        var searchType = $('#SearchType').val();

        if (searchText !== lastSearchText || searchType !== lastSearchType) {
            $("#SubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#SubmitButton").attr("value", "Search"); 
        }
        else {
            $("#SubmitButton").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#SubmitButton").attr("value", "Submit disabled until you change search criteria.");
        }
    }         

    $("#StarForm").submit(function (e) { 
        lastSearchText = $("#SearchString").val().trim();
        lastSearchType = $('#SearchType').val();
        onSearchChanged();
    });
});
```

Comment: Both this and Anthony's were great and appreciate their help.  The end solution was closer to Papa hence the tick.

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding your listeners here:

```
$("#SearchString").keyup(function () { EnableSubmit();});
```

You first need to check if the text is different ***before*** you call EnableSubmit(). What you are currently doing is calling the function whenever a key is pressed. Adding an if statement before EnableSubmit() should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Keep button disabled if the current search value is equal to the last submitted search value. I changed your `EnableSubmit` function to an `EnableDisableSubmit` and have added a variable `currentValue` to get the current value of the search input.

Here's the code:

```js
var LastChange;
 var currentValue;

 $("#SearchString").change(function(e) {
   EnableDisableSubmit(currentValue);
 });
 $("#SearchString").keyup(function(e) {
   currentValue = $(this).val();
   EnableDisableSubmit(currentValue);
 });
 $("#SearchType").change(function(e) {
   EnableDisableSubmit(currentValue);
 })

 function EnableDisableSubmit(txt) {
   if (txt !== LastChange) {
     $("#SubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#SubmitButton").attr("value", "Search");
   } else {
     $("#SubmitButton").attr("disabled", true);
     $("#SubmitButton").attr("value", "Submit disabled until you change search criteria.");
   }
 }

 $(function() {

   $("#SubmitButton").click(function(e) {

     $("#SubmitButton").attr("disabled", true);
     $("#SubmitButton").attr("value", "Submit disabled until you change search criteria.");

     LastChange = ($("#SearchString").val());

     var FormData = '{ "SearchString": "' + $('#SearchString').val() + '",' +
       '"SearchType" : "' + $('#SearchType').val() + '"' +
       '}';
     e.preventDefault();


   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id="SearchString" />
<button id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
```